# Flutter - Firebase with phone verification sends different amount of digits

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, sms

Recently I faced a problem with firebase phone authorization. I have added phone verification in my application. As we know firebase sends fixed amount (6 digit code) to verify users phone number. But from yesterday I am receiving 5 digit number and sometimes it sends 6 digits. Anyone knows what is the problem with firebase ?

Comment: Do the 5 digit codes work?

Comment: NO it does not work it gives this error - "[firebase_auth/sessıon-expıred] The sms code has expired. Please re-send the verification code to try again"